# MySQL InnoDB: A long semaphore wait:

Tags: mysql, innodb, semaphore

We had a production MySQL Issue this morning, the app was not getting responses back from the databases and started having issues.

The below is what I could find in the logs, can anybody explain to me what happened on MySQL and how i can avoid this event from occurring again?, we have no additional log entries before or after and I can't see what was running at the time.

```
Nov 27 07:44:34  mysqld[19527]: Aborted connection 1271090 to db: 'information_schema' user: 'cmon' host: '' (Got an error reading communication packets)
Nov 27 07:46:55  mysqld[19527]: InnoDB: page_cleaner: 1000ms intended loop took 15077ms. The settings might not be optimal. (flushed=923, during the time.)
Nov 27 07:47:16  mysqld[19527]: InnoDB: page_cleaner: 1000ms intended loop took 19703ms. The settings might not be optimal. (flushed=868, during the time.)
Nov 27 07:48:35  mysqld[19527]: InnoDB: A long semaphore wait:
Nov 27 07:49:06  mysqld[19527]: InnoDB: A long semaphore wait:
Nov 27 07:49:06  mysqld[19527]: InnoDB: A long semaphore wait:
Nov 27 07:49:37  mysqld[19527]: InnoDB: A long semaphore wait:
Nov 27 07:49:37  mysqld[19527]: InnoDB: A long semaphore wait:
Nov 27 07:50:08  mysqld[19527]: InnoDB: A long semaphore wait:
Nov 27 07:50:08  mysqld[19527]: InnoDB: A long semaphore wait:
Nov 27 07:50:39  mysqld[19527]: InnoDB: A long semaphore wait:
Nov 27 07:50:39  mysqld[19527]: InnoDB: A long semaphore wait:
Nov 27 07:51:10  mysqld[19527]: InnoDB: A long semaphore wait:
Nov 27 07:51:10  mysqld[19527]: InnoDB: A long semaphore wait:
Nov 27 07:51:41  mysqld[19527]: InnoDB: A long semaphore wait:
Nov 27 07:51:41  mysqld[19527]: InnoDB: A long semaphore wait:
Nov 27 07:51:41  mysqld[19527]: InnoDB: A long semaphore wait:
Nov 27 07:52:12  mysqld[19527]: InnoDB: A long semaphore wait:
Nov 27 07:52:12  mysqld[19527]: InnoDB: A long semaphore wait:
Nov 27 07:52:12  mysqld[19527]: InnoDB: A long semaphore wait:
Nov 27 07:52:43  mysqld[19527]: InnoDB: A long semaphore wait:
Nov 27 07:52:43  mysqld[19527]: InnoDB: A long semaphore wait:
Nov 27 07:52:43  mysqld[19527]: InnoDB: A long semaphore wait:
Nov 27 07:53:14  mysqld[19527]: InnoDB: A long semaphore wait:
Nov 27 07:53:14  mysqld[19527]: InnoDB: A long semaphore wait:
Nov 27 07:53:14  mysqld[19527]: InnoDB: A long semaphore wait:
Nov 27 07:53:14  mysqld[19527]: InnoDB: A long semaphore wait:
Nov 27 07:53:45  mysqld[19527]: InnoDB: A long semaphore wait:
Nov 27 07:53:45  mysqld[19527]: InnoDB: A long semaphore wait:
Nov 27 07:53:45  mysqld[19527]: InnoDB: A long semaphore wait:
Nov 27 07:53:45  mysqld[19527]: InnoDB: A long semaphore wait:
Nov 27 07:54:16  mysqld[19527]: InnoDB: A long semaphore wait:
Nov 27 07:54:16  mysqld[19527]: InnoDB: A long semaphore wait:
Nov 27 07:54:16  mysqld[19527]: InnoDB: A long semaphore wait:
Nov 27 07:54:16  mysqld[19527]: InnoDB: A long semaphore wait:
Nov 27 07:54:47  mysqld[19527]: InnoDB: A long semaphore wait:
Nov 27 07:54:47  mysqld[19527]: InnoDB: A long semaphore wait:
Nov 27 07:54:47  mysqld[19527]: InnoDB: A long semaphore wait:
Nov 27 07:54:47  mysqld[19527]: InnoDB: A long semaphore wait:
Nov 27 07:55:04  mysqld[19527]: Aborted connection 1449537 to db: 'information_schema' user: 'cmon' host: '' (Got an error reading communication packets)
Nov 27 07:55:04  mysqld[19527]: Aborted connection 1450163 to db: 'information_schema' user: 'cmon' host: '' (Got an error reading communication packets)
Nov 27 07:55:15  mysqld[19527]: InnoDB: page_cleaner: 1000ms intended loop took 4665ms. The settings might not be optimal. (flushed=1009, during the time.)
Nov 27 07:58:00  mysqld[19527]: InnoDB: page_cleaner: 1000ms intended loop took 160462ms. The settings might not be optimal. (flushed=708, during the time.)
Nov 27 08:02:01  mysqld[19527]: InnoDB: A long semaphore wait:
Nov 27 08:02:32  mysqld[19527]: InnoDB: A long semaphore wait:
Nov 27 08:02:32  mysqld[19527]: InnoDB: A long semaphore wait:
Nov 27 08:02:32  mysqld[19527]: InnoDB: A long semaphore wait:
Nov 27 08:02:54  mysqld[19527]: Aborted connection 1450788 to db: 'information_schema' user: 'cmon' host: '' (Got an error reading communication packets)
Nov 27 08:02:54  mysqld[19527]: InnoDB: page_cleaner: 1000ms intended loop took 290741ms. The settings might not be optimal. (flushed=650, during the time.)
```

Comment: check you database for errors and restart it. Of Course don't forget to backup your data first.

Comment: Your page cleaner is also taking many times too long. Either your system load is way too high (perhaps the server is swapping?) or else your disks are failing.

Comment: Yes i found out the server was swapping at the time. No idea why as MySQL is limited to using 80/128GB and THP is disabled.

Answer (score 0):

This *may* solve a problem with "page_cleaner":  Lower this:

```
lru_scan_depth = 50
```